# How to install cinelerra-hv ?

Tags: apt, software-installation, ppa, source, cinelerra

There is cinelerra-hv and two other types which are based on its code, cinelerra-gg and cinelerra-cv.

As for cinelerra-cv, I found here a good explanation how to install it by adding a ppa.

However, after researching for how to install cinelerra-hv, I am still puzzled how to achieve it.

The reasons for my confusion are:

- all explanations on how to install cinelerra from ppa i found are referring to cinelerra-cv, so I do not know if there is a ppa for cinelerra-hv after all.
- I found a step by step guide to an older version of cinelerra-hv on how to install from source, I did not understand it and when I reproduced the steps it did not work for reasons unknown to me.
- I could not find any step by step tutorial, neither on cinelerra.org nor the source-forge download-page of the most recent cinelerra-hv, I do not understand if I simply cant find it or whether it is so self-explanatory on how to install it from source, that it was not necessary to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cinelerra-HV is the non community version of cinelerra (Heroine Virtual LTD maintained) and does not have ppa. Cinelerra-HV is original author's version cinelerra from Adam Williams http://www.heroinewarrior.com/cinelerra.php

If your system 64-bit, you can run HV 6 (pre-compiled package) without installation. https://sourceforge.net/projects/heroines/files 
(choose cinelerra-6-x86_64.tar.xz   2016-11-17  43.6 MB).

If your system 32-bit, you should compile it yourself.

However, compilation of Cinelerra-HV is not a trivial task for newbies.
You should install all dependencies.

Some info can be found on my blog http://linuxvideoediting.blogspot.com/2016/11/compilation-cinelerra-hv-6.0.html
But it is in Russian.

Cinelerra-GG 5.1 is the merging `CV 2.3 + HV 6`.

https://cinelerra-cv.org/download.php

Any questions - here -> http://lists.cinelerra-cv.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/cinelerra

Note that settings directories of HV and CV have the same name  /home/user/.bcast

Do not forget to remove settings directory before running a other branch.

Settings directory of Cinelerra-GG  is  /home/user/.bcast5